# "target" subdirectories in package explorer in recent eclipse (at least 4.13 + maven 3.6.x)

Tags: eclipse, maven

So in Eclipse 4.13 (and maybe a few versions before) with embedded maven 3.6.x, when I open a simple, almost empty, maven project, it shows me these non existant subdirectories in project explorer :

```
target/generated-sources/annotations
target/generated-sources/test-annotations
```

If I remove them from source directories (in project > properties > java build path), eclipse creates these directories and add them as sources again, so I guess it comes from some maven plugin conf somewhere.

How do I get rid of these 2 directories display when I don't have use of them ?

And since this problem probably comes from a combination of maven 3.6 + Eclipse 4.13 + some maven dependency, here is my pom.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>my.comp</groupId>
  <artifactId>file-mgt-backend</artifactId>
  <version>${revision}</version>

  <name>My project</name>

  <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <springfox.version>2.9.2</springfox.version>
    <!-- Downgrade to 3.1.1 needed for Eclipse bug : https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=547340 -->
    <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
    <!-- Sane default when no revision property is passed in from the commandline -->
    <revision>0-SNAPSHOT</revision>
  </properties>

  <scm>
    <developerConnection>(...)</developerConnection>
  </scm>

  <!-- Paramètres de publication de l'artifact -->
  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      (...)
    </repository>
  </distributionManagement>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.9.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
      <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
      <version>${springfox.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
      <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
      <version>${springfox.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
      <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.2</version>        
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Comment: I am also using the same version of eclipse and embeded maven, but I am getting the issue you explained. Can you try to create a simple maven project and also try to import a maven project to narrow down the issue ?

Comment: Yes, the most simple maven project has the issue, and it does not appear with STS 3.9.7 (based on eclipse 4.10).

Comment: Try to update m2e eclipse plugin and try.

Comment: "No update found" for m2e, it's a fresh install of STS 4.4.0

Comment: You are finally left with only one choice that is to configure local maven settings with Eclipse. Go preference and make settings for local maven installation.

Comment: By the way, I am using Eclipse Version: 2019-09 R (4.13.0), Build id: 20190917-1200, I am not getting this problem. Are you using a different build version ?

Comment: oh ok, you are not. You wrote "but I am getting the issue you explained" so I was confused about your suggestions. I've found the module responsible to set these directories as sources (it's maven compiler plugin : https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#generatedSourcesDirectory) but I don't think it's the issue, it should be an evolution of m2e, it's strange you can't reproduce.

Comment: About my Eclipse, it's a bit more recent, and it's packaged by Spring : 201909171436 and my m2e is : 1.13.0.20190716-1624